# Replacing ceiling light/fan switch with TP-Link Kasa HS200

Tags: electrical

I'd like to replace this ceiling fan/light switch with a Kasa switch.  I believe it is a 2 way switch, as that is the only switch for that fan/light.

The original light switch has 3 wires going into it.  The kasa switch has 2 live (black), 1 ground (green), 1 neutral (white).

How do I wire this to my kasa switch? Thanks!

PS. Ignore how the old light switch is barely on the screws. I just put it back on for the photo (while the breaker is off).

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Does that black wire really go in to the red wire connector with a bare ground wire? The angle and the heavy HDR make it hard to tell. If you can throw together a diagram in Paint showing what is connected where it will help a bunch.

Comment: Yes it looks like it does.  I've added more pictures for clarification.  Thanks.

Comment: Cudos for finding a real cowboy installation out there in the wild.

Answer (score 5):

##### TL;DR Clean Up the Mess First

You have a mess. The most obvious piece being the bare wire (by definition, "ground") and the black wire (normally either "hot" or "switched hot").

There are often old things that are grandfathered. But as long as ground wires have been a regular thing they have not been connected to hot/switched hot wires. So this must be fixed first.

It may or may not even be *possible* to install this switch in this location. A simple switch just connects to hot and switched hot, and possibly ground. A smart switch like this TP-Link typically needs hot (a.k.a., "line"), switched hot (a.k.a., "load"), neutral and ground. There are some switches that allow using ground instead of neutral, and there are plenty of switches where even though they say they need ground they will function even without ground (though generally that's only if they have a good neutral). This switch has wires for everything, so it *must* have neutral.

Many switch boxes don't have neutral. Newer code requires neutral in order to support smart switches/timers/etc. But older code did not require. A hint that your box doesn't have neutral is that it looks like it has white wire used as hot or switched hot. But it really isn't very clear, and the ground wire connected to a black wire is a **HUGE** red flag. Red wires are good (because they usually go along with a newer setup - black hot, white neutral, red switched hot) but of course red flags are not good.

Back to your problem: You have a black/white cable and a black/white/bare cable. You need to identify where each *wire* is currently connected, and then we can figure out what to do next. Possibilities include:

- Incoming hot
- Outgoing hot (i.e., to another switch or a receptacle)
- Switched hot (controlling the light)
- Neutral (not likely here, and you *need* neutral for this switch, so that's most likely going to be a problem)
- Ground (the bare wire *should* be ground...)

That will probably require opening up the light fixture junction box, and possibly some other boxes. Some diagnostics can be done by separating *all* the wires and (carefully) turning on power to see which wire(s) is hot. Determining what else is on this circuit may be useful as well.

Comment: House was built in 1997 and the other switches have neutral wires. This last one threw me a curveball.  I've attached a diagram, but it seems you figured out the layout.

This makes me not even want to touch it anymore because "it works" already with the dumb switch wired on there.  
Question.  What reason would there be to have 2 wires connected to the bottom on both the screw and the push in?  Does this have anything to do with it controlling a light/fan combo?

Is there anything I can test with my multimeter to share back here to help solve this problem?

Comment: @RoyEP3 In 1997 neutral wasn't required. But bare ground definitely was not OK to be connected to hot or neutral or switched hot. The 2 wires for light and fan is an interesting possibility, but if that was the case then that would make wire 1 incoming hot and wires 4 & 5 neutral. Bare ground as neutral is wrong but understandable (because ground & neutral are connected in the main panel) but black 4 as neutral is totally wrong - white is not always neutral but neutral is always white (at least in standard cables). The test is to disconnect all 5 wires and see which is hot with the breaker on.

Comment: With a little bit of luck, you can swap the fan/light end so both are connected to the one pair of black and white wires, then install the smart switch in this box. It's entirely possible this was just someone who completely forgot that you can connect two devices to a single wire. Maybe. Hopefully.

Comment: I finally got around to testing all the wires.  Hopefully this will help figure out what's going on in this switch.

Using the bare wire #5 as my ground, I tested the others with a multimeter and found the following:
#3 = 120
#2 = 15
#1 = 0
#4 = 0

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they have used the black and bare wire for a neutral. The white wires have been used for hot and switch leg.

Comment: This doesn't really add anything to the answer that's been here for months. Care to expand on this after checking out how to write a [good answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)?